# Как получить миниатюру файла фото, видео...?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Здравствуйте!

Как получить миниатюру файла - например если это фото, то (маленькое фото), видео (кадр видео) аналогично сделано в стандартной галерее android, если это документ word - то значок W, excel значок X и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Android SDK метода с подобным функционалом нет, однако Вы можете написать его самостоятельно.

Логика работы подобного метода довольно проста: в зависимости от расширения файла он будет возвращать требуемую миниатюру. Для Word и Excel миниатюры можно задать статически, для получения превью фото и видео можно использовать что-нибудь вроде [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).